# Trouble with scraping forum website using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a beginner **R** user trying to scrape data from this forum: https://forum.singaporeexpats.com/

I need user info, topic, thread, messages.

My code just isn't working, and I am going insane trying to figure out why. Would really appreciate any help I can get!

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# Scrape thread titles, thread links, authors and number of views

h <- read_html("https://forum.singaporeexpats.com/")

threads <- h %>%
html_nodes("#page-body .list-inner a") %>%
html_text()

thread_links <- h %>%
html_nodes("#page-body .list-inner a") %>%
html_attr(name = "href")

# Custom function to scrape messages in each thread

scrape_messages <- function(thread_link){
read_html(thread_link) %>%
html_nodes(css = ".content") %>%
html_text() %>%
str_squish
}

# Create master dataset (and scrape messages in each thread in process)

master_data <- 
tibble(threads, thread_links) %>%
mutate(messages = map(thread_links, scrape_messages)) %>%
select(threads, messages, thread_links)

# Save to csv

write.csv(master_data, "forum_practice.csv")
```

There are 2 errors:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `messages = map(thread_links, scrape_messages)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! './viewforum.php?f=84&sid=2cbd9cb015d48679e299696905ac1701' does not exist in current working directory.
```

I tried various other solutions but the CSV always returns completely empty.

Comment: Check values in `thread_links` ,  those are relative links (i.e  `./viewforum.php?f=84&sid=2cbd9cb015d48679e299696905ac1701'` ) and if passed to `read_html()` as-is, it will look for local files. You'd need to prepend the base URL, `https://forum.singaporeexpats.com/`, to those values first.  Besides, there are currently 68448 topics / 657004 posts and 342293 members. Are you asking how to scrape all that content?